# How to remove spacing at the beginning of a word?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to remove the spacing at the beginning of my `h1` tag. Please see the attached screenshot. I have highlighted the `h1` tag in blue so you can see the extra space at the beginning of the wording. It amounts to around 1 or 2 pixels. The space is not margin or padding. The space is definitely from the h1 element because I have removed the rest of the elements from the page. What could this space be? and how can I remove it?

**UPDATE:** Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jU43x/) for the example code

[image]

Comment: All of the modern browsers have built-in tools that will show exactly what tags correspond to "boxes" on the screen.

Comment: Try `letter-spacing`, `word-spacing` etc.

Comment: Please show some markup that replicates the problem (HTML + CSS).

Comment: @Juhana Give me a few moments and i'll follow up with a jsfiddle

Comment: @str never thought of those, I'll try them...

Comment: It's just the fonts letter-spacing, no?

Comment: It might simply be part of the kerning or other rendering aspects of some letters..

Comment: Hey guys, please see my updated question for the jsfiddle

Comment: The jsfiddle does not illustrate the issue. You need to set e.g. a background color or, better, a border to see the “gap”.

Comment: My screen shot illustrates the issue. The jsfiddle provides the code used to create the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This vertical sliver of whitespace before each character is almost certainly a characteristic of the font you're using to render this `<h1>` text. Font designers manage inter-character spacing by putting some of the space at the end of characters and some of it at the beginning. They typically optimize this for both optical (eyeball) alignment at the beginnings and ends of justified lines and also for nicely balanced intra-word spacing.

If you must get rid of it, there are some things you could try.

1. Negative tracking. Try a small negative CSS `letter-spacing` attribute like `.05em`. This will cram your characters a little closer together. Be subtle with this effect.
2. A boldface font choice. Often the font designer makes the font bold by thickening the strokes symmetrically about their centerline. This may eat up a bit of the leading whitespace.
3. As a last resort, render the text into a graphic (png or gif) and then trim its edge. This won't look very good.

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestions. Regarding your suggestions: I tried negative `letter-spacing` which although condensed the letters, it didn't impact the beginning whitespace. A boldface font might be an option, but I think overall I'd prefer to keep this same style. Option 3 would solve the problem, but then would result in Google throwing its SEO toys out of the pram. Even though this problem looks unsolvable in this case, at least now I know the reason for the whitespace!

Answer (score 0):

The analysis by @OllieJones is correct: you are dealing with details of font design. In effect, you are trying to undo some decisions by the font designer, in a specific context; there is no general mechanism for that.

What you can do is to shift the content left. The amount of the shift depends on the specific font properties and the characters involved. In the given case, a shift of 5px pushes the “C” against the left edge. But beware that if the first letter is something else, it probably gets pushed too much. Different letters have, on purpose, different spacing around them in the font design.

Content can be shifted using positioning or, perhaps safer, using auxiliary markup and a negative margin:

```
<style>
h1 > span {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -5px
}
</style>
<h1><span>Covered with grass then detained</span></h1>
```

This lets you use normal styling for the `h1` element. For example, if you draw a border around it, the letter “C” will touch the border. I presume this what you want (though it would be a typographic error). Alternatively, shift the `h1` element left simply by setting a negative left margin on it.

Answer (score -1):

In this case the issue was due to the padding on the body of the HTML markup.

Adding this clears it;

```
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
```

Whether this is the solution in your scenario is impossible to say without the full code.

http://jsfiddle.net/jU43x/5/

Comment: There is a bout 1px and that could well be down to the wrapping put on the cell by JSFiddle or the actual font itself, as others have expressed. To down vote my answer for that is just disrespectful.

Comment: Why has my comment to this answer been deleted? And for the record, it wasn't me who down-voted this answer.

Comment: It seems there are some editors who aren't doing a very good job. Its a hot topic at the moment.

Comment: In fact have a +1. Appreciate you trying to help!

Answer (score -1):

Adding `margin-left: -3px;` to the h1 tag will fix this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jU43x/6/)

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1.2;
font-size: 97px; 
margin-left: -3px;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing the exact same but it feels a _'hackish'_ solution

Comment: @henrywright I might be wrong, but I think the default stylesheet adds some margin to the `h1` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I did check both margin and padding on the h1 element via the Chrome tools. If you right click on the element the browser will show you where padding or margin has been applied via coloured 'boxes'